# Async/await not working in a for-of loop defined in createAsyncThunk

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm having trouble trying to get an async await to work inside a for loop when using `createAsyncThunk`. I expected that `dispatch(performRunAllCells())` will call the API `updateBrowser()` synchronously for each `cell` in the `editor.cells` array in order. Instead, the dispatch resulted in `updateBrowser()` being called asynchronously all at once. What is happening here?

```
export const performRunAllCells = createAsyncThunk(
  'editor/runAllCells',
  async (_, { dispatch, getState, rejectWithValue }) => {
    const { notebook: { selectedDataset } } = getState() as {notebook: {selectedDataset: string}};
    const { editor } = getState() as {editor: EditorState};

    try {
      let results: DataEntity | undefined;
      for (const cell of editor.cells) {
        dispatch(setCellStatus({ id: cell.id, execStatus: '*' }));
        results = await updateBrowser(selectedDataset, cell.editorContent);
        dispatch(setCellStatus({ id: cell.id }));
      }
      return results;
    } catch (e) {
      return rejectWithValue(e.response.data);
    }
  },
);
```

**Edit**

Currently I'm testing `updateBrowser()` with a setTimeout:

```
export async function updateBrowser(selectedDataset: string, editorContent: string): Promise<DataEntity> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('test');
      resolve({
        raw: editorContent, html: 'Test', console: 'Test',
      });
    }, 3000);
  });
}
```

I was able to know if it's synchronous/asynchronous through the console log above. Currently, it is printing multiple "test" at once.

Comment: Can you share the code for `updateBrowser`? Also, can you clarify how you currently determine that this happens synchronously vs asynchronously?

Comment: @phry, I have edited my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I made a mistake somewhere else and the code wasn't actually being called. It is working now after fixing it.